# Change row height in SWT tree

Tags: java, tree, swt, eclipse-rcp, row-height

I have tree, i want to change the row height of that tree.
I have tried adding listener, SWT.MeasureItem and EraseItem as well, but still the row height is not changing.

There is the function in inbuilt Tree class but, that function is not public , so I am not able to use that function

Please suggest some approach to change the row height of the tree.

Comment: Setting the `height` field in the `MeasureItem` event can increase the size of the rows (but not decrease it). Also note that all rows have to have the same height.

Comment: @greg-449 i want to decrease the height for all rows. How can i do it

Comment: There is no official way to do that. On macOS it is possible to access some of the SWT internals to do it but that make the code macOS specific. I don't know if it is possible on other platforms.